# How to Create an Interactive Selection Based Visualization

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am totally new to Power BI, so your help would be much appreciated.
I have gone through a couple of beginners tutorials and am now trying to practice by creating my own dashboards.

If I have a table that looks like this:

[image: table]

I want to have the dashboard let me select (by clicking) the person I want to view, and once clicked, it should highlight (change color) of the names of the sports that they play.

Examples:

[image: mike]

and:

[image: jacob]

How would I go about accomplishing that?

Thank you for your time!

I've looked into several visualization options, but I believe I am missing something still in terms of knowing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this in the future, here's the solution that I found.

There is a visualization that's available for free in the Power BI marketplace called ChickletSlicer that lets you do exactly that.

Cheers.